# Importing .csv file with tidydata

Tags: r, tidy

I am having difficulty importing my data in the way I would like to from a .csv file to tidydata.

My data set is made up of descriptive data (age, country, etc.) and then 15 condition columns that I would like to have in just one column (long format). I have previously tried 'melting' the data in a few ways, but it does not turn out the way I intended it to. These are a few things I have tried, I know it is kind of messy. There are quite a few NAs in the data, which seem to be causing an issue. I am trying to create this specific column "Vignette" which will serve as the collective column for the 15 vignette columns I would like in long format.

```
head(dat)
    ID       Frequency Gender Country Continent         Age
1 5129615189 At least weekly female  France    Europe 30-50 years
2 5128877943  At least daily female   Spain    Europe  > 50 years
3 5126775994 At least weekly female   Spain    Europe 30-50 years
4 5126598863  At least daily   male Albania    Europe 30-50 years
5 5124909744  At least daily female Ireland    Europe  > 50 years
6 5122047758 At least weekly female Denmark    Europe 30-50 years
                       Practice             Specialty  Seniority AMS
1 University public hospital centre   Infectious diseases 6-10 years Yes
2             Other public hospital   Infectious diseases > 10 years Yes
3 University public hospital centre        Intensive care > 10 years Yes
4 University public hospital centre   Infectious diseases > 10 years  No
5            Private hospial/clinic Clinical microbiology > 10 years Yes
6 University public hospital centre   Infectious diseases  0-5 years Yes
   Durations V01 V02 V03 V04 V05 V06 V07 V08 V09 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15
1          range   7   2   7   7   7   5   7  14   7  42  42  90   7  NA   5
2          range   7  10  10   5  14   5   7  14  10  42  21  42  14  14  14
3          range   7   5   5   7  14   5   5  13  10  42  42  42   5   0   7
4          range  10   7   7   5   7  10   7   5   7  28  14  42  10  10   7
5          range   7   5   7   7  14   7   7  14  10  42  42  90  10   0   7
6 fixed duration   7   3   3   7  10  10   7  14   7  90  90  90  10   7   7

 dat_long %>% 
  gather(Days, Age, -Vignette)

dat$new_sp = NULL
 names(dat) <- gsub("new_sp", "", names(dat))

dat_tidy<-melt(
 data=dat,
 id=0:180,
 variable.name="Vignette",
 value.name="Days",
 na.rm=TRUE
 )

 dat_tidy<- mutate(dat_tidy,
              Days= sub("^V", "", Days)
              )
```

It keeps saying "Error: id variables not found in data: NA"
I have tried to get rid of NAs but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing you are loading the `melt` function from `reshape2`. I will recommend that you try `tidyr` which is basically the next generation of `reshape2`.

Your error is presumable that the argument `id=0:180`. This is basically asking it to keep columns 0-180 as "identifier" columns, and melt the rest (i.e. create a new row for each value in each column).

When you subset more column indices than columns in a data.frame, the non-existing columns are filled in with pure `NA` - you asked for them, so you get them!

I would recommend loading `tidyr`, as it is newer. There should be some new verbs in the package that are more intuitive, but I'll give you a solution with the older semantic:

```
library(tidyr)
dat_tidy <- dat %>% gather('Vignette', 'Days', starts_with('V'))
# or a bit more verbose
dat_tidy <- dat %>% gather('Vignette', 'Days', V01, V02, V03, V04)
```

And check out the comment @heck1 for asking even better questions.

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you so much!